# ERROR 405 Method Not Allowed after hosting in IIS but works in development mode

Tags: reactjs

I am using Web Api C# as backend for my application. I have enable CORS globally in the project.

config.EnableCors();

The frontend is developed in Reactjs. All the methods work in development mode but when I deployed the application in IIS, the post method does not work. I receive the following error message.

"Request failed with status code 405" Method not allowed"

Below is the api calling code.

axios(
{
method: 'POST',
url: URL,
data : JSON.stringify({partyid:'1234567'}),
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
}

Comment: It may be that `EnableCors` allows localhost by default but once you've deployed to a real URL you need to define which URL's you're enabling CORS for. So if you deploy to example.com you need to tell CORS that site is white listed. Otherwise anyone would be able to access your API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Micky. I hosted the site on my local IIS. My URL after hosting the site is http://systemip:9965/home.  Do I need to mention this URL/IP in CORS. I'm getting error(405 method not allowed) while checking with above URL, but working fine while testing with development mode i.e. http://localhost:3000

Comment: I'm passing * for all cors above the controller. [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Comment: I think you'd want to add it here [EnableCors(origins: "systemip:9966/", headers: "", methods: "*")]. You should want the trailing "/" or "/*" so the server will allow extra path. You may also need to define `https://systemip` or `http://systemip`

Comment: Thanks @Micky. After adding URL in cors, i was getting error "CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status", which later got resolved.